# What can be done about a user copying content into tag wikis without attribution?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, tag-wiki

[A user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1609555/sid) seems to be copying content into tag wikis without proper attribution. I think it's for the reputation (+2/edit) he gets for this.

Note that his edits are generally being approved by the community moderators, which might indicate a problem with reviewing standards. What can be done about this?

Comment: Not so much spamming as copying content into wikis (without attribution).

Comment: Mm, yes, you're right.

Comment: They being approved by regular users not diamond moderators.

Comment: I checked some of their latest suggestions to wikis and excerpts ([tag:tdbmemo], [tag:harfbuzz], [tag:ora-00903]), all look OK to me. Could you point to what **specifically** looks wrong?

Comment: I think the review page for tag wiki edits should link the the tag wiki guidelines, and perhaps even display a summary. I've been skipping these edit suggestions, since I'm too lazy ATM to figure out when to approve them.

Comment: The problem with copy&paste edits is that the content looks decent, but requires attribution. So one can't review the edit just from the edit page, but needs to research if it was plagiarized.

Comment: @CodesInChaos plagiarized is kind of harsh, it's not at all untypical for a tag wiki to be seeded with the elevator pitch of a project directly from the project web site (especially if open source and under a CC/GFDL license). However, yes, citation is required in all cases, and we _much_ prefer that users write original descriptions based on their knowledge of the tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've sent a message to the user to discuss this. It's not uncommon for tag wikis to be seeded with the 'elevator pitch' from an official project or product front page. However, citations are positively mandatory and we much prefer that original, first hand knowledge goes into the wiki, being the majority of the content.

In the future, It would be better to flag something like this for our attention. If you see someone making what you feel are questionable wiki edits, flag any of their questions or answers, select 'other' and tell us to look at their history, specifically at wiki edits.

Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: OK, thanks. I wasn't sure where to flag; in future I'll just pick an answer and do it there.